# How to Display Image for Duration x in StoryBoard MediaTimeLine and play another video or image after First Image Duration is Completed?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, storyboard

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    MediaTimeline mediaTimeline;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetStoryboard(0, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), @"File PAth HERE");          
    }

    private void SetStoryboard(double beginLeft, double endLeft, TimeSpan duration,string path ,bool flag=true)
    {                       
        mediaTimeline = new MediaTimeline();
        mediaTimeline.Duration = new Duration(duration);
        mediaTimeline.Source = new Uri(path);
        mediaTimeline.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(mediaTimeline, mediaElement);
        storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.SlipBehavior = SlipBehavior.Slip;
        storyboard.Children.Add(mediaTimeline);
        storyboard.Begin(this, true);

    }

    private void MediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        SetStoryboard(0, 10, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),@"File Path Here", false);
    }

}
```

Here is my XAML Code:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="_grid">
    <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" LoadedBehavior="Manual" MediaEnded="MediaElement_MediaEnded"></MediaElement>
</Grid>
```

The above code is working fine for 5 seconds when the path is given of any Image File but when the Duration is given more than 5 seconds it still shows the Image for 5 seconds and play video.I want to know how to Display Image for 30 seconds and then play the video.

Comment: Have you found the fix?

Comment: Yes i found the fix @Sham